# GoogleカレンダーのAPI連携での出力について＜＞

Tags: google-calendar-api

Googleカレンダーのイベント内容をAPI連携にてスプレッドシートに出力しています。
しかしながら「<>」の記号付きで内容が出力されてしまいます。

<>が出ないようにする方法はありますか？

調査した範囲ですとblob(Binary Large OBject)というJavaScriptのオブジェクトが関係しているようです。

動作環境：Googlechrome/90.0.4430.72（Official Build） （64 ビット）

---

追記：こちらの質問の修正版を新規投稿しました。
[GoogleCalendarAPIでイベントを取得すると、<html-blob>形式で返ってきてしまう。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/89660/googlecalendarapi%e3%81%a7%e3%82%a4%e3%83%99%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8-html-blob%e5%bd%a2%e5%bc%8f%e3%81%a7%e8%bf%94%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8d%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86)

Comment: まずはそれが再現できるコードを質問に記述して、ほかの人も再現できるようにしましょう。参考[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: API の結果の時点で不要なカッコが付いているのか、それとも何らかの処理をする過程で付いてしまっているのかが今の内容だと分からない気がします。