# GoogleCalendarAPIでイベントを取得すると、<html-blob>形式で返ってきてしまう。

Tags: python, python3, google-api, google-calendar-api

Googleカレンダーのイベント内容をAPI連携にてスプレッドシートに出力する機能を実装しています。

## ■事象

Google Calendar APIを使うと、以下添付画像のように、`<html-blob>`や`<br>`などがついた形で取得されてしまいます。
繰り返しの予定や招待のイベントのように、手入力以外の入力方法を使った場合にそのような形式になってしまうようです。
[image: Google Calendar API html-blob形式]

どちらも開発者側ではなく、ユーザー側ですが、以下の記事と同じような事象です。

- https://origin-discussions2-us-dr-prz.apple.com/en/thread/253667481
- https://cyapu.com/2018/04/11/googlecalendar/

## ■該当コード

GoogleCalendarAPIでカレンダー情報を取得している箇所のPythonコードです。
以下のコードで取得した時点で、もうすでに<>形式になっているため、GoogleCalendarAPIの使い方がよくないのかなと思っています。

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId = calendar_id,singleEvents = True,timeMin = min_day, timeMax = max_day, timeZone = "Asia/Tokyo", maxResults = "2500").execute()
```

リファレンス：https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list

## ■質問

`<html-blob>`のような形式になっている部分もあるため、そのようなタグ形式を変換する記述や設定をどこかでしなければならないのかと思いました。
何か他に考慮するべき箇所があるのでしょうか？
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: そもそもGoogleCalendarの説明の部分は修飾可能なリッチエディタのようです。https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resourceを見ても「Description of the event. Can contain HTML. Optional.」とあるのでHTMLタグがあること前提で開発をしないといけないのではないですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so 
ご回答ありがとうございます。  
申し訳ありません、調査不足でした…。  
  
＞HTMLタグがあること前提で開発をしないといけない  
この通りですね。これを踏まえて修正方法を検討しようと思います。